# Modify notes with external app

Tags: android, call, external

Hi want create an app for Android which has to open create and modify o note file (only text) with an external app. I know the path i don't know how to call an external app. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below @Delafuente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Below is the code to read a text file from `sdcard` root :**

```
package com.dEvElOpIt.writepad;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;

public class FileOperations {
    public FileOperations() {
    }

    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    public Boolean write(String fname, String fcontent) {
        try {
            String fpath = "/sdcard/" + fname + ".txt";
            File file = new File(fpath);
            // If file does not exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(fcontent);
            bw.close();
            Log.d("Suceess", "Sucess");
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String read(String fname) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String response = null;
        try {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            String fpath = "/sdcard/" + fname + ".txt";
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fpath));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
            response = output.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Now you can do as mentioned below to get the data of `text` file :**

```
String fileName = input.getText().toString();
FileOperations fop = new FileOperations();
String text = fop.read(fileName);
```

where `fileName` is the name of file which is to be loaded from root of `sdcard`.

**Do as mentioned below, if you want to save data as text file in `sdcard` root :**

```
FileOperations fop = new FileOperations();
            fop.write(mTitleText.getText().toString(), mBodyText.getText()
                    .toString());
            if (fop.write(fileName, fileContent) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        mTitleText.getText().toString()
                            fileName+ ".txt Successfully saved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I/O error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

where `fileName` is the name of file which is to be loaded from root of `sdcard`,
 and `fileContent` is the Content of text file to be saved.

**Don't forget to add Permission below to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` includes `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, so the latter is really ininfluent in this case. You just need it for read-only access.

Comment: Oh I forgot.Thanks, I'll update the answer :) @DerGolem